# Sarparse IO stats graphs in Cacti

Tags: cacti

I found one SAR template for DISK IO Stats. I have copied `sarparse_cpuparse.php`, `sarparse_iostat.php`,`sarparse.p1` to .`./scripts/`  and imported sar `template.xml` file.when we are creating new host in cacti. but we are getting below error

```
Running data query [10].
+ Found type = '4' [Script Query].
+ Found data query XML file at '/ebsvol/cacti/resource/script_queries/host_disk_stats.xml'
+ XML file parsed ok.
+ <arg_num_indexes> missing in XML file, 'Index Count Changed' emulated by counting arg_index entries
+ Executing script for list of indexes '/usr/bin/php -q /ebsvol/cacti/scripts/sarparse_iostat.php 172.16.200.220 index' Index Count: 0
+ Executing script query '/usr/bin/php -q /ebsvol/cacti/scripts/sarparse_iostat.php 172.16.200.220 query index'
+ Executing script query '/usr/bin/php -q /ebsvol/cacti/scripts/sarparse_iostat.php 172.16.200.220 query name'
```

please find the attachment error. [image]